# Is there a way to check the content of a table against a XML file using <td> tags

Tags: javascript, html

i have made a Sudoku table with some numbers pre-loaded from a XML file. I have another XML file with the complete puzzle numbers and want to check the number input against the numbers in the XML file which should be in the same order.

I have tried using document.getElementsByTagName("td").value to get the input value but I've gotten nowhere this way.

this is my table.

```
<table id="grid">
 <tr id="one">
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="two">
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="three">
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
 </tr>  
 <tr id="four">
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="five">
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="six">
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="seven">
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="eight">
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="nine">
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="numer1"></td>
    <td class="numer2"></td>
    <td class="number"></td>
 </tr>
```

this is what i have tried with JS

```
function hint(){
if (document.getElementById("easyS").value == "easy1" || 
document.getElementById("hardS").value == "hard1"){
    var request1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
request1.open("GET", "puzzle1.xml", false);
request1.send(null);
var xmldoc = request1.responseXML;

var numbers1 = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("number");
var numArray1 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < numbers1.length; i++){
    numArray1.push(numbers1[i].firstChild.data)
}
var printNum1 = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].value;
x = printNum1.length;
console.log(printNum1);
if (printNum[x] !== numArray1[x]){
    alert("wrong number");
}
}
console.log(hint());
```

}

this next bit of code does work and tried to do something similar but can't get it:

```
 function solvePuzzle(){
  var request1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request1.open("GET", "puzzle1.xml", false);
   request1.send(null);
var xmldoc = request1.responseXML;

var numbers1 = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("number");
var numArray1 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < numbers1.length; i++){
    numArray1.push(numbers1[i].firstChild.data)
}
var printNum1 = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
x = printNum1.length;
while(x--){
    printNum1[x].innerHTML = numArray1[x];
}
```